# Simple system of nonlinear ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to solve a system of ODEs of the form:

$$\frac{d^2a}{dt^2} = \frac{-1}{(a-b)^2}$$

$$\frac{d^2b}{dt^2} = \frac{+1}{(a-b)^2}$$

and with the following boundary conditions:

$$a'(0) = 0$$

$$b'(0) = 0$$

$$a(0) = a_0$$

$$b(0) = b_0$$

where a<sub>0</sub> and b<sub>0</sub> are just arbitrary real constants representing the initial values of a(t) and b(t), with a<sub>0</sub> > b<sub>0</sub>.

I'm working on a problem in partial differential equations (with some irrelevant coefficients, that I've taken out of the problem here) that relies on being able to solve a system of ODEs of this type. I remember doing this problem in my introductory ODE class a couple of years ago, but I don't remember what the solution was or how to solve it.

If this helps, I've figured out that the values of a(t) and b(t) will converge at some time in the future (t > 0) such that $$a(t) = b(t) = \frac{a_0+b_0}{2}$$ although I don't know the earliest such value of t.

---

Edit: I may be mistaken, but it appears that this system of ODEs is essentially equivalent through a simplifying substutition of variables to a single ODE:

$$\frac{d^2c}{dt^2} = \frac{1}{(c-d_0)^2}$$

$$c'(0) = 0$$

$$c_0 < d_0$$

Thanks to Hans Ludmark for the suggestion.

Edit 3: Moved solution to a separate answer.

Comment: For a start, $(a+b)''$ is identically zero, and $(a+b)'(0)=0$, so $a(t)+b(t)$ is constant. You can use this to reduce the problem to an ODE in just one of the variables (say $a$).

Comment: I briefly thought of a similar method earlier, since this system of DEs is analogous to the two-body problem in classical physics, which has a well-known solution method where you change the frame of reference to one where one of the particles is stationary and the other one moves relative to it. This problem is actually like two particles of m_1 = m_2 = 1, constrained to a line and initially at rest, with the constant of gravitation omitted. But I couldn't see what the DE of a single variable would be after eliminating b. I'll try looking into that again. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Say, what is the point of declaring in an Edit that *you've got a solution to the problem* and describing in details what you found with the use of WA, one hour after an answer with a full solution was posted? I am not following.

Comment: I didn't realize I could answer my own question. I've moved it to a separate answer now. I'm keeping your answer marked as most helpful, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $a''(t)+b''(t)=0$ for every $t$ hence $a'(t)+b'(t)=a'(0)+b'(0)=0$ for every $t$ hence $a(t)+b(t)=a_0+b_0$ for every $t$. Plugging $a(t)=a_0+b_0-b(t)$ in the differential equation for $b''(t)$ yields $$2b''(t)b'(t)=\frac{2b'(t)}{(a_0+b_0-2b(t))^2}=\left(\frac1{a_0+b_0-2b(t)}\right)',$$ hence, using $b'(0)=0$, $$b'(t)^2=\frac1{a_0+b_0-2b(t)}-\frac1{a_0-b_0}=\frac{2(b(t)-b_0)}{a_0+b_0-2b(t)}.$$ Since $b'(0)=0$ and $b''(t)\gt0$ for every $t$, $b'(t)\geqslant0$ and $b(t)\geqslant b_0$ for every $t$, hence $$b'(t)=+\sqrt{\frac{2(b(t)-b_0)}{a_0+b_0-2b(t)}}.$$ Thus, $b'$ is increasing on its interval of definition $[0,T)$ until $b'(t)\to+\infty$ and $b(t)\to\frac12(a_0+b_0)$ when $t\to T$, where $$T=\int_{b_0}^{(a_0+b_0)/2}\sqrt{\frac{a_0+b_0-2x}{2(x-b_0)}}\mathrm dx=\frac{a_0-b_0}2\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{1-s}s}\mathrm ds=\frac\pi4(a_0-b_0).$$ Note that $b(t)$ solves the implicit equation, valid for every $t$ in $[0,T]$, $$t=\frac{a_0-b_0}2\int_0^{2(b(t)-b_0)/(a_0-b_0)}\sqrt{\frac{1-s}s}\mathrm ds.$$ Finally, all these functions are different scalings of one unique solution, to wit, consider the change of variable $$b(t)=b_0+(a_0-b_0)\beta\left(\frac{2t}{a_0-b_0}\right),$$ then $\beta$ does not depend on $(a_0,b_0)$ and solves the differential equation $$\beta(0)=\beta'(0)=0,\quad\beta'(\tau)=\sqrt{\frac{\beta(\tau)}{1-\beta(\tau)}},\quad0\leqslant\tau\lt\frac\pi2,$$ whose implicit solution is $$\tau=\sqrt{\beta(\tau)(1-\beta(\tau))}+\arcsin\sqrt{\beta(\tau)}.$$ A plot of the function $\beta$:

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

Comment: "Plugging a(t)=a0+b0−b(t) in the differential equation for b''(t)..." I think that's slightly incorrect. a(t) and b(t) always add to the mean of the initial values, not the sum of the initial values. Did you mean "Plugging a(t)=(a0+b0)/2-b(t) into..."?

Comment: @Robi Rahman why would he do that since he proved the following: a(t)+b(t) = $a_0 +b_0$?
You can even check that using the latter will give you the limit for both function: L+L= $a_0 +b_0 \implies L= \frac{a_0+b_0}{2}$

Comment: Oh oops. That's a dumb mistake on my part. You're right - I was thinking that the mean of a(t) and b(t) is always equal to the mean of a0 and b0, but got that mixed up with the fact that the sum of a(t) and b(t) is equal to the sum of a0 and b0. This is embarrassing... so anyway, disregard my previous comment.

Comment: "Since b′′(t)>0 for every t, b′(t)⩾0 and b(t)⩾b0 for every t..." Is this true? a starts greater than b, but as a decreases and b increases, don't their values intersect at (a0+b0)/2 and then cross each other? Except I am unsure what exactly happens, because b'' is infinity at that value of t, and a'' is negative infinity.

Comment: @mvggz Thanks. $ $

Comment: No pb Did :)
@Robi Rahman, he only used the fact that: $f \geq 0 \implies \int f \geq 0$, with f successively being b" and b'and integrating between 0 and t.

Comment: Yes this is true. The curves never intersect since, when $t\to T$, $a''(t)\to-\infty$ and $b''(t)\to+\infty$, hence $a$ and $b$ are defined only on $[0,T)$.

Comment: Are you sure? Won't they just intersect sort of like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot[{Surd[x%2C+3]%2C+-Surd[x%2C+3]}%2C+{x%2C+-1%2C+1}])?  Those two functions momentarily have infinite slope but are defined before, after, and through that point.

Comment: Please explain the meaning of $a''(t)=-1/(a(t)-b(t))^2$ when $a(t)=b(t)$.

Comment: I don't understand if it's even meaningful at all, but presumably it behaves like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%28Surd[x%2C3]%2Cx%29), right? The derivative acts strange around x=0 but the function goes on fine right through it.

Comment: See previous comment.

Comment: Which previous comment? Sorry, I'm new to stackexchange and can't tell which one you're referring to. If you mean the immediately-preceding one, I don't know anything about the meaning of a''(t) except that a''(t) approaches negative infinity as a(t) approaches b(t).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Hans and Did! I've got a solution to the problem.

Since d^2a/dt^2 + d^2b/dt^2 = 0 and da/dt = db/dt = 0 at t=0, we know that for all t, a + b = a_0 + b_0. Therefore, after rearrangement, we can combine the following two equations:

$$\frac{d^2b}{dt^2} = \frac{+1}{(a-b)^2}$$

$$a = a_0 + b_0 - b$$

to get

$$\frac{d^2b}{dt^2} = \frac{1}{(a_0+b_0-2b)^2}$$

and since a<sub>0</sub> and b<sub>0</sub> are just arbitrary constants, define c = a<sub>0</sub> + b<sub>0</sub> to simplify the equation. The system has then been reduced to a single nonlinear ODE. WolframAlpha can solve this; the answer is [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%28derivative%28b%28t%29%2Ct%29%2Ct%29%20%3D%201%2F%28c-2b%28t%29%29%5E2) (stated implicitly). Then, having solved for b(t), a(t) can be obtained by trivial substitutions.